# R: Efficient addition of random noise to a raster dataset

Tags: raster, r

**Question**

What is the fastest way to assign random noise (from a truncated normal distribution) to an existing DEM in R

**What I have now**

I have a DEM to which I want to add random noise for a normal distribution. This process is to be iterated numerous times as part of a monte carlo-esque type scheme. I start by defining a function to give me such a constrained *random* value as described:

```
#' Get random value from a truncated normal distribution
#' a = min value
#' b = max value
#' m = mean
#' sd = standard deviation
library(truncnorm)

rand_noise<-function(a=0,b=10,m=5,sd=2){
    val=rtruncnorm(n=1,a=a, b=b, mean=m, sd=sd)
    return(val[1])
}
```

For this example let's say we have a DEM as follows:

```
library(raster)

# get data
dem <- getData('SRTM', lon=16, lat=48)

# reproject to utm zone 33N (the data is for Austria)
tsrs <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs " 
dem <- projectRaster(dem, crs = tsrs)

# aggregate it
dem=aggregate(dem, fact=5)
```

I'd like to create a second (matching) raster field with random values using my pre-defined function *as fast as possible*. Currently I'm converting to a dataframe and using lapply to assign the function to each xy pair:

```
# convert raster to df to assign noise
df=as.data.frame(dem, xy=TRUE)
df$noise=apply(df, 1, function(x) rand_noise())

keeps=c('x','y','noise')
df=df[keeps]
noise=rasterFromXYZ(df)
crs(noise) = crs(dem)
plot(noise)
```

[image]
I can then add the noise to the original DEM:

```
noisy=dem+noise
```

Is there a faster way to create and add the noise (as described above) without having to convert to a dataframe? Something akin to lapply? The outlined approach above will be slow for multiple iterations.

Comment: Why not just use raster::calc to apply your function?

Comment: Create an empty raster, `noise`, with the same extent, res etc, and do: `noise[] = random_thing(n)` where `random_thing(n)` generates a vector of `n` numbers, the same as `runif`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a raster with the same parameters as the `dem`, and fill it with noise in one go. First a simple `dem` because the GADM download fails for me:

```
> dem = raster(matrix(1:30, nrow=6))
> plot(dem)
```

Now make an empty raster like `dem`, and fill it:

```
> noise = raster(dem)
> noise[]=rtruncnorm(n=ncell(noise),a=0, b=10, mean=5, sd=2)
> plot(noise)
```

You can even do:

```
> dem[] = dem[] + rtruncnorm(n=ncell(dem),a=0, b=10, mean=5, sd=2)
```

if you don't mind overwriting the `dem` and don't care about the noise values much.